# FFMPEG filter instances names don't work with "sendcmd"?

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg

I have two `drawbox` filter instances that I need to animate separately.
I've used `sendcmd` for the one instance already, and it worked fine.

But when I've added the second one, I gave a name to both of them like this:

```
drawbox@one=0:0:iw:ih:red:fill,drawbox@two=0:0:iw:ih:black:fill
```

Then, I've tried to use `sendcmd` like this:

```
drawbox@one=0:0:iw:ih:red:fill,drawbox@two=0:0:iw:ih:black:fill,
sendcmd=c='0.0-5.0 [expr] drawbox@one w W*(T/5)
           0.0-5.0 [expr] drawbox@two h H*(T/5)'
```

But that didn't work, the rectangles stayed still.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm still running into this on 6.1. Were you able to fix it with custom instance names or did you just switch to the Parsed_x_y syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a bug in the latest stable build (version 6.0, 2023-03-04) of FFMPEG!
When I updated it to the latest "master" build, it started to work!

P.S.: I've also made it work on that release version like this:

```
drawbox=0:0:iw:ih:red:fill,drawbox=0:0:iw:ih:black:fill,
sendcmd=c='0.0-5.0 [expr] Parsed_drawbox_0 w W*(T/5)
           0.0-5.0 [expr] Parsed_drawbox_1 h H*(T/5)'
```

I found this syntax here - https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-April/035975.html

Comment: What's wrong with my question and answer?